# In RTF BIP word template, need to change the background color of the table based on a field where background color is also a field

Tags: xml, oracle-apex, bi-publisher

I've downloaded the XML data from Apex and designing RTF template using BI publisher on Word. There are dynamic color values for each invoice eg: #ff0000 for INVOICE_NO 001 and #ff00ff for INVOICE_NO 002

In a table, need to add the field value INVOICE_NO and need to add the background color of the table as field VALUE COLOR.

I've put the code below but the color is just displaying as black

Please correct the XML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to change `red` to `<?VALUE_COLOR?>`

Some examples of background color coding in the RTF file:

**Every other row is gray**

```
<?if@row:position() mod 2=0?> 
<xsl:attribute name="background-color" xdofo:ctx="incontext">lightgray</xsl:attribute><?end if?>
```

**Red if > 1000**

```
<?if:debit>1000?>
 <xsl:attribute xdofo:ctx="block" name="background-color">red</xsl:attribute>
<?end if?>
```

**Color options:**

To change the color attribute, you can use either the standard HTML names (for
example, red, white, green) or you can use the hexadecimal color definition (for
example, #FFFFF).

**Examples found in:**

Oracle® XML Publisher
Report Designer's Guide
Release 12
Part No. B31410-01